# Bootstrap 4 - "Complete JavaScript" vs "Complete JavaScript Bundle"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

What am I missing?  The examples use min.js.  The bundle.min.js has more code, but I can't find a description of that extra code...

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/

Code:

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js vs https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As [shown in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/contents/#js-files), the "bundle" includes popper.js for you, the other does not.

[image]

Comment: basically they moved the tooltip to its own lib ? what for ? it's such a small lib for it to be independed